# Unable to connect to AWS MYSQL RDS instance using PHP via AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Hi I am trying to connect to Amazon Web Services MYSQL RDS Instance using PHP code stored in AWS EC2 instance. My AWS EC2 instance is connected properly and i have installed Apache, PHP and MYSQL using PuTTY SSH Client. However, when I execute my PHP code from browser, I get following error:

```
ec2-.....compute.amazonaws.com (EC2 Public DNS) is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

**Here is my PHP code:**

[image]

**NOTE: I have used AWS MYSQL RDS instance endpoint(without port number) as "DB_SERVER", master username and master password of AWS MYSQL RDS instance. I have stored my PHP file in /var/www/html.**

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to connect to my AWS MYSQL RDS instance via AWS EC2 instance???

Comment: This type of issues is alot easier to debug if you separate the different components that could be at fault here. First try to connect to the RDS instance using a mysql shell on the EC2 instance, and after you make sure it works - proceed to debug your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you pls post sample code to "connect to RDS instance using a mysql shell on the EC2 instance". I am new to this arena. @YaronIdan

Comment: It's described pretty thoroughly here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Comment: Also, make sure that your security groups actually grant the application access to the database.

Comment: okay thanks. Will try doing that and reply. @YaronIdan

Comment: @YaronIdan thanks buddy for the help. I did the way you told me to and found that my EC2 instance was missing mysql server installation. I installed that and modified my PHP file a bit and now got the connection.

Comment: Great, happy to help. I'm gonna write it as an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of issues is alot easier to debug if you separate the different components that could be at fault here. First try to connect to the RDS instance using a mysql shell on the EC2 instance, and after you make sure it works - proceed to debug your PHP code.

Instructions for connecting to RDS can be found here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Answer (score 1):

I would start by testing the connection on the command line:

```
mysql -h *cluster end point* -P 3306 -u *username* -p *password*
```

Verify that the cluster end point in your AWS RDS page is **authorized**

[image]

Or make sure the security group used allows the connection to the cluster.